# Convert linq date to short date

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following query from Sale table and want to filter it by short date.

```
Dim query = From c In db.Sale Where c.TRAN_DATE=TranDateParam
            Group By c.TRAN_DATE Into Total_Payment = Sum(c.PAYMENT),Discount_Amount = Sum(c.DISCOUNT) _
            Select Total_Payment, Discount_Amount, TRAN_DATE
```

-My c.TRAN_DATE value is included time.Example:"2013-05-01 10:09:49.107"
-My TranDateParam value is short date format.Example:"2013-05-01"

Therefore I cannot compare c.TRAN_DATE=TranDateParam. I was try many method covert c.TRAN_DATE to short date but unsuccessful.

I try below method but is failed:

```
c.Tran_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
c.Tran_Date.Value.ToShortDateString()
CDATE(c.Tran_Date)
```

How to I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any errors with the approaches you tried?  How about `c.TRAN_DATE.ToShortDateString()` (note that C# is case-sensitive).

Comment: I try c.Tran_Date.Value.ToShortDateString(). The error message is:"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: What is the data type of your `TranDateParam`?

Comment: string, I try CDATE(c.Tran_Date) before but it don't have date time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed. I just change my query as below:

```
Dim query = From c In db.Sale Where c.TRAN_DATE= CDate(TranDateParam) _
            Group By c.TRAN_DATE Into Total_Payment = Sum(c.PAYMENT),Discount_Amount = Sum(c.DISCOUNT) _
            Select Total_Payment, Discount_Amount, TRAN_DATE
```